# How to make GDB break at each system or library function call?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I want to do that without specifying the name or address of all the system or library functions.

I would basically want to use gdb as strace or ltrace but with the possibility to have a look at the stack or memory addresses in real time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Newer versions of gdb support "catch syscall", which should do what you want

Comment: That is great, thanks. Is there a way to do that for library functions or shared library functions though?